# Wrap text in a JTextPane when pane width exceeds a specified value

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, word-wrap

My GUI displays a log in a JTextPane, which is inside a JScrollPane, which occupies the left side of a JSplitPane. The right side of the JSplitPane holds the interesting part of the GUI. The width of the log pane is typically narrow (20), but is increased when the user wants to view the activity. If the log text is wrapped the displayed text is pretty useless when the log pane is narrow, but if some log entries are long, the size of the log pane needs to be increased to occupy most of the GUI to view the entries.

I understand that JTextPane does not naturally wrap text, and that other postings on Stack Overflow describe how text can be wrapped. However, I would like the text to be wrapped only when the pane is wider that some supplied limit, say 100. So, when the pane is narrow, just the beginning of each message is shown, and if the user wants to see the full text, the pane width is increased and the text is wrapped to the window width.

If there's no way to do this, I will turn off wrapping and format the text to some fixed width before writing it to the pane.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a `if (this.getWidth > 100) ...` in your paintComponent method.

Comment: So add a ComponentListener to your textpane and switch ON/OFF the wrapping depending on the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that JTextPane does not naturally wrap text

That is wrong. By default a JTextPane does wrap text.

Check out [Text Pane No Wrap](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/) for more information on this topic which forms the basis for the solution below.

You need to override the `getScrollableTrackViewportWidth()` method. I think it should be:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane()
{
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
    {
        return getParent().getSize().width > 100;
    }
};
```

Edit:

This problem seems to be related to the text in the text pane. Don't know if it is the length of the text or the non alphabetic characters in the text that cause a difference:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TextPaneNoWrap
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
            {
                Dimension d = getParent().getSize();
                System.out.println(d);

                return false;
            }
        };
        textPane.setText("one two three four five six\nthis wraps at 39");
//      textPane.setText("import javax.swing.event.*;\nthis wraps at 111");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextPaneNoWrap");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JLabel("Some Component"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane( textPane ));
        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Edit2:

Seems to work ok when using a "wrapper" panel that implements the Scrollable interface:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TextPaneNoWrap
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

//      textPane.setText("one two three four five six\nthis wraps at 39");
        textPane.setText("import javax.swing.event.*;\nthis wraps at 111");

        JPanel wrapper = new NoWrapPanel(textPane);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextPaneNoWrap");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JLabel("Some Component"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane( wrapper ));
        frame.setSize(300, 100);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    static class NoWrapPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable
    {
        public NoWrapPanel(JComponent component)
        {
            setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
            add( component );
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
        {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction)
        {
            return 20;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
        {
//          return false;
            return getParent().getSize().width > 100;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction)
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see my comment had the polarity reversed on whether the unmodified JTextPane wraps text, thanks. This solution works great, mostly. However, if I modify getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() so it always returns false, there should be no text wrapping, and that's what happens for the width => 131. When the width of the JTextPane < 131, the text wraps. Are there circumstances when the value of getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() is ignored? I am not setting the preferredSize or minimumSize on either the JTextPane or the JScrollPane that contains it. Thanks, again.

Comment: @BruceS, Interesting, I do see the same behaviour. I'm not sure why this happens. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for verifying it!